# Drawing in easements with traverse

Tags: arcgis-pro, parcel

I'm trying to figure out how to add the following in the ArcGIS Pro traverse grid:

"99.86 feet along a curve to the right, said curve having a delta angle of 48-54'08", a radius of 117 ft and a chord of 96.86 feet bearing S49-32'11"W "

I know that I can use the traverse tool to fill in the delta angle, the radius, and the curve direction but I can't find a place where I can input all of the above:

```
ft along curve
delta angle 
radius
chord 
chord distance
chord bearing
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the main question, you only need three parameters for a curve, you don't have to add everything. But this is how I would add your curve in the traverse grid of the Traverse tool.

First, make sure you have your Angular Units set to Degrees Minutes Seconds and your Direction Units set to Quadrant Bearing in the Project options on the Units tab.

Then choose "Chord" from the drop-down in the Direction column heading in the traverse entry grid.

[image]

Second, choose Delta Angle from the furthest right column heading drop-down in the traverse entry grid.

[image]

Now click in the Direction entry box and type 49.3211-3 and press Enter.

That moves you to the Distance entry box. Type 0 and press Enter.

That moves you to the Radius entry box. Type 117 and press Enter.

That moves you to the Delta Angle entry box. Type 48.5408 and press Enter.

[image]

I use the DD.MMSS-Quadrant format to enter bearings and DD.MMSS format for deltas because it's less typing and I can stay on the number keys. The quadrant numbers are - 1 = NE, 2 = SE, 3 = SW, and 4 = NW.

For the radius entry, positive numbers are for curves to the right, negative numbers are for curves to the left. If your curve would have been to the left, you would have entered -117 instead.

If this is a tangent curve you wouldn't need to enter the chord bearing, you can just type * and then enter. That indicates the bearing from the previous course is the tangent bearing for the curve being entered.